# Notice (8): Undefined index:cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

```
 - I have facing problem with notices and warning, please help me to
       resolved 

       Here is error:

       >Notice (8): Undefined index: energy_improvements_id
       >[APP/Controller/CustomerEvaluationsController.php, line 17] 

       Here is controller code:

           public function generate() {
               $this->loadModel('User');  
               $user=$this->User->save($this->request->data);

               $this->loadModel('UserUtilities');  
               $this->request->data['UserUtilities']['user_id']=$this->User->id;

               $this->UserUtilities->save($this->request->data);

               $data['energy_improvements_id']=$this->request->data['energy_improvements_id'];

               foreach ($data['energy_improvements_id'] as $key => $value) {
                   $temp[$key]['energy_improvements_id']=$value;
                   $temp[$key]['user_id']=$this->User->id;   
               }

               $this->set('user_id',$this->User->id);
                $this->loadModel('EnergyImprovementUser');
             $this->EnergyImprovementUser->deleteAll(array('user_id' => $this-   >User->id));
```

//here is line 41 temp code occurs solving Notice (8): Undefined index:cakephp 
//Notice (8): Undefined variable: temp

//[APP/Controller/CustomerEvaluationsController.php, line 41]

```
  $this->EnergyImprovementUser->saveAll($temp);
       $this->layout='';
        //load the Electricity Utilities
        $this->loadModel('ElectricUtility');
        $electric_utilities = $this->ElectricUtility->find('list',      array('fields' => array('ElectricUtility.id', 'ElectricUtility.electric_utility')));
        $this->set(compact('electric_utilities'));
```

Comment: check if $this->request->data['energy_improvements_id'] is empty

Comment: If it's sating it undefined then pr($this->request->data) and see if it is or not?

Comment: @tiGer yes error occurs when  it is empty.. if it is not empty then works fine..but some time i want that field is empty..so what is the solution for that.? i am tried with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for empty before foreach

```
if (!empty($this->request->data['energy_improvements_id'])){

    foreach ($this->request->data['energy_improvements_id'] as $key => $value) {
        $temp[$key]['energy_improvements_id']=$value;
        $temp[$key]['user_id']=$this->User->id;   
    }

       $this->EnergyImprovementUser->saveAll($temp);
       $this->layout='';
       //load the Electricity Utilities
       $this->loadModel('ElectricUtility');
       $electric_utilities = $this->ElectricUtility->find('list',      array('fields' => array('ElectricUtility.id', 'ElectricUtility.electric_utility')));
       $this->set(compact('electric_utilities'));

}
```

Comment: now showing Undefined variable: temp [APP/Controller/CustomerEvaluationsController.php, line 41]

Comment: Where is your that temp code, put your whole code in question.

Comment: See the updated answer, $temp will be saved only when not empty.

Comment: Great, If that worked than you can upvote and mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

you have to define the id or create if it's new:

```
$this->User->create();
```

And

```
 $this->UserUtilities->create();
```

After try a debug($this->request->data) for see if your form send the Id ( energy_improvements_id )

Answer (score 0):

php_value max_input_vars 10000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 10000 
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 10000

reset the value in .htaccess (OR) php.ini file.